# MS Remote IE is giving me Chrome browser instead

Tags: internet-explorer, remote-desktop

I just signed up at https://remote.modern.ie for web dev testing. It didn't seem to be working right, so I went to Browser Spy, and got this:

[image: Remote IE userAgent says Chrome/36.0]

What's going on?

Comment: This site is for programming questions. We are not general software tech support.

Comment: Perhaps I was misled by https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/ie/en-US/8ba70824-dba2-4425-bc75-247c2c29bde1/ie-web-development-support-moving-to-stack-overflow?forum=iewebdevelopment
Where should I ask this instead?

Comment: @Marc B. While not precisely worded as a specific coding issue, I do believe the question (and solution) has value for web developers trying to figure out what's changing in new versions of IE.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you're seeing here is the new user agent string reported by the new IE rendering engine (see [NeoWin article](http://www.neowin.net/news/heres-how-to-enable-the-new-ie12-trident-mode-in-internet-explorer-on-windows-10) for a little background).

[image: IE12's customization flags]

IE12's User Agent is:

`5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/39.0.2171.71 Safari/537.36 Edge/12.0`

Chrome 40's User Agent looks like this:

`5.0 (Windows NT 10.0; WOW64) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/40.0.2214.93 Safari/537.36`

Notice IE's UA string is now remarkably similar to Chrome's - this is deliberate:

The reality is that IE is now generally just as compatible with most HTML5 standard features as Chrome, Firefox, Safari, etc. and (except for increasingly rare cases) should be treated by most websites just as they treat Chrome etc.

By removing "MSIE ..." properties from IE's UA string, there's now a FAR greater likelihood that most sites will render just as well as Chrome etc. even if the site was built to compensate-for/block/degrade on older versions of IE.

Comment: Huh. Microsoft's beta browser is indeed pretending to be Chrome. https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/hh869301%28v=vs.85%29.aspx